# Rails 4 function in controller not running

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, simple-form, has-many-through

I have some code for a Rails 4 project I'm working on. It uses active_record (mysql2), and there is a `has_many :through` relationship that works properly when I interact through `rails c` (in either production or development). When I try to submit the relationship in a form (I am using simple_form), I can't seem to get it to save.

Here is how my information is currently set up (just showing snippets, I can't really show the whole source):

## Model:

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :resource_categories, through: :categorizations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource_categories
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
```

## Form:

```
= simple_form_for @resource do |f|
  = f.association :resource_categories
```

## Controller:

```
# POST /resources
# POST /resources.json
def create
  @resource = Resource.new(resource_params)
  set_categories(@resource, params[:resource][:resource_category_ids])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @resource.save
      format.html {
        redirect_to @resource, notice: 'Resource was successfully created.'
      }
      format.json {
        render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @resource
      }
    else
      format.html {
        render action: 'new'
      }
      format.json {
        render json: @resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /resources/1
# PATCH/PUT /resources/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @resource.update(resource_params)
      set_categories(@resource, params[:resource][:resource_category_ids])
      format.html {
        redirect_to @resource, notice: 'Resource was successfully updated.'
      }
      format.json {
        head :no_content
      }
    else
      format.html {
        render action: 'edit'
      }
      format.json {
        render json: @resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      }
    end
  end
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list
# through.
def resource_params
  params.require(:resource).permit(
    :title, :slug, :ancestry, :status, :author_id, :published, :parent_id,
    :resource_category_ids, :preview, :body
  )
end

def set_categories(resource, categories)

  # Clean out the existing categories (if there are any)
  unless resource.resource_categories.blank?
    resource.resource_categories.each do |category|
      resource.resource_categories.delete(category)
    end
  end

  unless categories.blank?
    categories.each do |category|
      unless category.blank?
        resource.resource_categories << ResourceCategory.find(category)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I issue the following commands using `rails c -e production` (or just plain `rails c`) it works (In this example, I assign all categories to all resources):

```
Resource.all.each do |resource|
  ResourceCategory.all.each do |category|
    resource.resource_categories << category
  end
end
```

It seems like my problem is that the controller is not calling the helper function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
def create
  @resource = Resource.new(resource_params)    
  @resource.set_categories(params[:resource][:resource_category_ids])
  ..
end
```

Move the method in the `Resource` model:

```
def set_categories(categories)

  # Clean out the existing categories (if there are any)
  unless new_record?
    unless resource_categories.blank?
      resource_categories.each do |category|
        resource_categories.delete(category)
      end
    end
  end

  unless categories.blank?
    categories.each do |category|
      unless category.blank?
        resource_categories << ResourceCategory.find(category)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`@resource` is instance variable of your Controller, you don't need to pass it to a method. Perform all your operations directly on the instance variable.

OP still had problem while saving the record, changed `:resource_category_ids` to `:resource_category_ids => []` in `resource_params` method:

```
def resource_params 
params.require(:resource).permit( 
:title, :slug, :ancestry, :status, :author_id, :published, :parent_id, 
 :preview, :body, :resource_category_ids => [] 
) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought that would do it, but unfortunately it does not solve the issue. What looks like is happening is the bit that clears the categories out is running (I populated some in the console and ran through the edit form; the relation got cleared out as expected), but it is not populating the `@resource.resource_categories` relation with the new ones. Narrows it down some, but I'm still confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: Marking as correct. Thanks for sticking with me Kirti Thorat!

Comment: No Worries Mylan. Glad to help :)